# Automatically activate a virtual environment when cd to Poetry project

Tags: python, python-poetry

I want to automatically activate a Poetry virtual environment when I run

```bash
cd /path/to/a/python/project/
```

Is there a easy way to do so?

Comment: Make `cd` an alias or a function in your shell.

Comment: For GNU/Linux users who use the `zsh` shell, [`zsh-activate-py-environment`](https://github.com/se-jaeger/zsh-activate-py-environment) does this task for you.